# How to search in currently opened folder using selected line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode. How can I search (`workbench.view.search`) in currently opened folder using selected line (`expandLineSelection`) via a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform), and this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+z",                // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "runInSearchPanel",
  "args": {
    "isRegex": false,
    "triggerSearch": true,
    "filesToInclude": "${relativeFileDirname}",  // many other path variables as well

    // all the other search options are available, like 'matchCase',
    // 'find', 'replace, etc.
  }
}
```

any **selection** will be searched for in the current file's parent directory.  If you don't specify a find query, the selection will be used as the query.

You could put this together with a macro extension, here using [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), like this:

```
{
  "key": "alt+z",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "expandLineSelection",
      "cursorLeftSelect",  // to get rid of the trailing newline
      {
        "command": "runInSearchPanel",
        "args": {
          "isRegex": false,
          "triggerSearch": true,
          "filesToInclude": "${relativeFileDirname}"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

[image: search line expansion macro]

[I see that `expandLineSelection` includes the trailing newline.  But it doesn't seem to affect the resuts.  In any case, I added `"cursorLeftSelect"` to the above macro to get rid of that trailing newline.]